# file is not defined after importing it

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import a python file (`ChessEngine`) into another python file (`MainChess`).
When I call a function from that file, it says

> "ChessEngine" is not defined

Both files are in the same folder (Chess).
I am using version 3.11

I tried to use:

```
from Chess import ChessEngine
```

but this returned

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Chess'
```

I then tried to use:

```
from ChessEngine import *
```

but when I called a function from ChessEngine, it came up with the problem of "ChessEngine" not being defined

Comment: The last example should have worked if you hadn't prefixed the name of the function with `ChessEngine.`.

Comment: Try `from .Chess` and make sure that the file name is then `Chess.py` -- aka follow the case of the file

Comment: The asterisk version imports `ChessEngine.foo` as just `foo`, `ChessEngine.bar` as `bar`, etc. If you want to `import ChessEngine` then that's what you need to say.